# Understanding proof of theorem 2.4 in Stein Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Suppose $f = u+iv$ is a complex-valued function defined on an open set $\Omega$. If $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $\Omega$ then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $f'(z) = \partial f/\partial z$.

[image: .]

In the proof, they first write $u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y) =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}h_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}h_2+|h|\psi_1(h)$. How can I just write like that?

Comment: Hint: isolate $\psi_1(h)$ to one side of the equation. Do you recognize the other side and why it converges to $0$ as $|h| \to 0$?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I can see it's a derivative of $u$ at $(x,y)$. it converges to $0$ since we assumed $u$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$. In the proof, why we need continuously differentiable condition then?

Comment: My understanding is that continuous differentiability of $u$ says that the partials exist and are continuous, which implies that the Jacobian matrix of $u$ (in this case, the gradient) satisfies the definition of a multivariable derivative. The existence of the partials alone is not enough. I believe you can get away with the weaker result that $u$ has a total derivative, but perhaps the authors wanted to phrase the condition as a pair of partial differential equations. I'm not much of an analyst so frankly I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I guess they wanted to formulate their theorem such that it tells us how it's normally used in practice. In many cases where we really use the equations, we'd prove real differentiability by testing the partials for continuity anyway. Though it's a pet peeve of mine that it's so rare to see the stronger and more elegant version using only real differentiability, where even the proof is way more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $u(x+h_1,y+h_2)$ as $$u(x,y)+\bigl(u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y+h_2)\bigr)+\bigl(u(x,y+h_2)-u(x,y)\bigr).$$But, by the mean value theorem, there are maps $\theta_1,\theta_2\colon\Omega\longrightarrow[0,1]$ such that\begin{multline}u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y+h_2)=h_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigl(x+\theta_1(x,y)h_1,y+h_2\bigr)=\\=h_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+h_1\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigl(x+\theta_1(x,y)h_1,y+h_2\bigr)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)\end{multline}and that\begin{align}u(x,y+h_2)-u(x,y)&=h_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y+\theta_2(x,y)h_2)\\&=h_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)+h_2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y+\theta_2(x,y)h_2)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)\right).\end{align}Since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ are continuous, if you define $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\colon\Omega\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ by$$\varphi_1(h_1,h_2)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigl(x+\theta_1(x,y)h_1,y+h_2\bigr)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)$$and$$\varphi_2(h_1,h_2)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y+\theta_2(x,y)h_2)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y),$$you have $\varphi_1(0,0)=\varphi_2(0,0)=0$, $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are continuous at $(0,0)$, and$$u(x+h_1,y+h_2)=u(x,y)+h_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+h_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial h}(x,y)+h_1\varphi_1(h_1,h_2)+h_2\varphi_2(h_1,h_2).$$So, define $\psi(h_1,h_2)=\sqrt{\varphi_1^{\,2}(h_1,h_2)+\varphi_2^{\,2}(h_1,h_2)}$, and you're done.